# Online Accounts Flickr unable to connect - Ubuntu 18.4

Tags: online-accounts, flickr

I am trying to connect my flickr account to ubuntu 18.4 in online accounts section in Settings but it's asking me to enable cookies in my browser. Although it's not in the browser, it's in Settings > Online Accounts, I enabled cookies on Firefox anyways but it didn't work.

Do you have any idea how can I get through this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I checked in some forums and I found a solution for this, it's still not clear for me how this fixed it, but it did.
Just ran the command : /usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-daemon --replace
And now I can create new flickr account on online accounts.